# Text Spacing Issue in Game Center

Tags: game-center

My "points" text runs together with my score. Do I simply add a space in iTunesConnect in my "Score Format Suffix" field?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1yrX.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to change `Score Format Suffix` from `itunesconnect` from "Points" to " Points" and it worked :)

Comment: Thanks!  Glad it was so simple.  Why on earth would they not have a space there by default?

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. Adding a space in front of the suffix, gets removed after saving it.

Comment: Maybe depends on you browser? Have you tried with another one eg Firefox?

Comment: I tried it with Safari, Chrome and Firefox. HTML escaping too. No way. Any definitive solution?

Answer (score 4):

```
&nbsp;
```

does the trick for me!